# Find the count of unique subset sums in a powerset

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory

Given a list of integers, I want to find the count of unique sums for all possible subsets of length $N$.

I don't want to know the sum, or the subsets, just the count of possible unique sums for subsets of length $N$.

Comment: Too difficult(somewhere near impossible), since it depends in the first place on the elements.

Comment: @Ahmed Please withdraw your comment. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list has $n$ distinct integers then a subset of size $N$ will have a maximum of $_nC_N$ distinct sums. The minimum number of distinct sums will be
$$N(n-N)+1   $$
for $0<N<n$. If $N=0$ or $N=n$, then the the number of distinct sums is $1$, the sum of the empty set ($0$) or the sum of the whole set, respectively.

The maximum is obvious, the proof of the minimum will have to await me getting some sleep (or some one else doing it). One possibly interesting question is whether every number between the minimum and the maximum can be attained for all $n$ and $N$.